# Problems rendering an image in gtk

Tags: c++, image, gtk, buffer, gtk3

I'm programming an application in c++ with a GUI in GTK3 that will show the images obtained from a genicam camera. I've got the official API of the camera that deals with it and extract returns an unsigned char* to the buffer where the image is contained.

The problem comes when I try to convert the image to a GTK format to render it in the GUI. I've tried with cairo and pixbuf, but I've problems in both of them, as the image is in MONO8 format, and pixbuf only deals with RGB. Cairo can deal with 8bit images, but only if they have an alpha channel, which is not the case.

Does someone know a way to approach this issue?
Thanks in advance